# Read Multiple txt files to multiple dataframes and concate later all dataframes to one

Tags: python, dataframe

I could only find the topics reading multiple txt files to one single dataframe. But I want to store them each as a different dataframe `( df1, df2, ... )` and later concate them together to one dataframe. Is there a fast way to do this ? Better what is the fastest way to do this ? That's one big point for me. The data names should not be used, they have the format `(year.month.day.hour.minute.second)` no txt in the end of the files to find. Thank you in advance. 
Right now I am just reading and putting in one file:

```
f in glob.glob("path_in_dir"):
    df = pd.read_table(f, delim_whitespace=True, 
               names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
               dtype={'A': np.float32, 'B': np.float32, 'C': np.float32,
                      'D': np.float32,'E': np.float32, 'F': np.float32,
                      'G': np.float32,'H': np.float32})

    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What did you try ? give us some code

Comment: @ArashHatami please check my edits

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider this approach: *I want to store them each as a different dataframe (df1,df2...) and later concatenate them*. Instead, save each similar dataframe in a larger container like list or dictionary. This avoids flooding your global environment with many (potentially hundreds) of separate objects.

Below you have only two objects  to maintain: 1) *df_dict*, with keys being *df1*, *df2*, ... and 2) *all_data*, where all dataframe elements are stacked together.

```
df_dict = {}

for i, f in enumerate(glob.glob("path_in_dir")):
    df_dict['df'+str(i+1)] = pd.read_table(f, delim_whitespace=True, 
                               names=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'),
                               dtype={'A': np.float32, 'B': np.float32, 'C': np.float32,
                                      'D': np.float32,'E': np.float32, 'F': np.float32,
                                      'G': np.float32,'H': np.float32})
# MASTER COMPILED DATAFRAME
all_data = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), ignore_index=True)

# FIRST THREE DATAFRAMES
df_dict['df1'] = ...
df_dict['df2'] = ...
df_dict['df3'] = ...
```

Comment: your solution is fitting well for my problem. Thank you really!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'your_file.txt', sep = '\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'your_second_file.txt', sep = '\t')
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'your_third_file.txt', sep = '\t')

master = pd.concat([df, df2, df3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the exact data structure instead I created few dummy files to perform the use case.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

datasets = []
for f in glob.glob("<Path to folder>"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', names=('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'), dtype={'Col1':str, 'Col2':int, 'Col3':float, 'Col4':str})
    datasets.append(df)
all_data = pd.concat(datasets, ignore_index=True)
print(all_data.head())
```

You can manipulate this code to make your code working.

Thanks

Comment: @Arsh didn't ask about the source information i.e. dataframe file, that's why I used list of DataFrames instead of using dictionary.